# Generate valid URL Google Places API

Tags: java, google-maps, google-api

I'm developing an application which has to do a Google Places API request.

http://code.google.com/intl/es/apis/maps/documentation/places/

I got the private key on the following website:

https://code.google.com/apis/console

Client ID: XXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com

Client secret:  YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY   (it looks like     vNIXE0xscrmjlyV-12Nj_BvUPaw=    )

I'm using this code to generate the URL:

```
public class UrlSigner {

  // Note: Generally, you should store your private key someplace safe
  // and read them into your code

  private static String keyString = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY";

  // The URL shown in these examples must be already
  // URL-encoded. In practice, you will likely have code
  // which assembles your URL from user or web service input
  // and plugs those values into its parameters.
  private static String urlString = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=40.717859,-73.957790&radius=1600&client=XXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&sensor=false";

  // This variable stores the binary key, which is computed from the string (Base64) key
  private static byte[] key;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
    InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, URISyntaxException {

    // Convert the string to a URL so we can parse it
    URL url = new URL(urlString);

    UrlSigner signer = new UrlSigner(keyString);
    String request = signer.signRequest(url.getPath(),url.getQuery());

    System.out.println("Signed URL :" + url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getHost() + request);
  }

  public UrlSigner(String keyString) throws IOException {
    // Convert the key from 'web safe' base 64 to binary
    keyString = keyString.replace('-', '+');
    keyString = keyString.replace('_', '/');
    System.out.println("Key: " + keyString);
    this.key = Base64.decode(keyString);
  }

  public String signRequest(String path, String query) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
    InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException, URISyntaxException {

    // Retrieve the proper URL components to sign
    String resource = path + '?' + query;

    // Get an HMAC-SHA1 signing key from the raw key bytes
    SecretKeySpec sha1Key = new SecretKeySpec(key, "HmacSHA1");

    // Get an HMAC-SHA1 Mac instance and initialize it with the HMAC-SHA1 key
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    mac.init(sha1Key);

    // compute the binary signature for the request
    byte[] sigBytes = mac.doFinal(resource.getBytes());

    // base 64 encode the binary signature
    String signature = Base64.encodeBytes(sigBytes);

    // convert the signature to 'web safe' base 64
    signature = signature.replace('+', '-');
    signature = signature.replace('/', '_');

    return resource + "&signature=" + signature;
  }
}
```

The code works fine: it returns a URL, but the URL gives this error:

> 1. That’s an error.
>      The requested URL /maps/api/place/search/json?.(...) was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

I tried to change the ClientID (XXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com) by XXXXXXXXXXX but it's still not working. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you reached no endpoint on the google-side. Even no places-api-service got your request.

try to use the following urlString:

```
private static String urlString = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=..."
```

the important difference is `googleapis` instead of `google`. Type your created url into your browser then you will see, that you get some json (even if it is a denied request). Then you know that your reached an api-endpoint.

**edit**: I think google has changed the domain to googleapis recently. The spanish-documentation which you use uses `google` and the english-documentation uses `googleapis`. I think the spanish documentation is not up-to-date. Maybe you post that info to google (maybe on the forum)

Comment: You're totally right, from now on I will use english documentation, thank you very much!